# Do I need to bring an original birth certificate with me when moving overseas?

Tags: paperwork, japan

I have recently accepted a job offer in Japan and am looking at getting my documents in order for moving there to live.

Do I need to bring my original birth certificate or will a certified copy be sufficient? I would prefer to keep the original safely with my family.

Comment: But - regardless of whether or not you expect to need it in the immediate future - as somebody who's moved internationally, I'd advise you to take it with you. I don't quite understand the implication that it will be safer with your family. If you stay abroad any length of time it's not so unlikely that you'll need it eventually. And when you do it's much better to have it yourself than to have to ask your parents (or whichever other family member you leave it with) to mail it to you internationally.

Comment: @ChrisH Just out of curiosity: For what practical purposes are birth certificates used and where? I am not exactly a youngster anymore, but I don't think I have ever in my life been required to show my birth certificate anywhere.

Comment: @jarnbjo The only example that immediately comes to mind is when I applied for citizenship. I certainly had to have my family send it to me for one reason or another several years before that, though I can't quite remember why.

Comment: (oh, and Germany is the "where" for that)

Comment: Nobody in Japan or at the Japanese embassy in the UK has ever seen my birth certificate. I've lived in Japan for 5 years now.

Comment: @jarnbjo My birth certificate has been required during the process of applying for a green card in the US. In that case, though, I actually needed to request a copy of my original long-form birth certificate, not just the card-sized one that I would normally have. I would expect that the immigration/naturalization process would generally require proof of birth.

Comment: You can get extra 'official' copies easily enough. I myself did bring my birth certificate with me when I moved overseas, and it actually was required of me to have after my passport had been stolen and, when getting a replacement, I had to demonstrate that they'd spelled my name incorrectly.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Ok, but if the purpose is to prove that you are born (as you say 'proof of birth'), shouldn't that be pretty self-evident if you are standing there in person and present your passport? Would you have been able to do that if you had not been born?

Answer (score 2):

I have lived in Japan for over three years now and I have not needed my birth certificate even once. Most forms you will encounter will ask for your passport or residence card, if at all.

(I didn’t need my birth certificate at home either, for that matter. The only reason I can think of would be if accidentally both my ID card and passport expired at the same time and I needed to prove I exist, but … no.)